# Printing contents of array just returns [null, null, null, null]

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class ArraysLab1 
{

    static String[] PresidentNames = new String[5];

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        //Declare an array of 5 strings
        String[] PresidentNames =  {"George Bush", "William J. Clinton", "George W. Bush", "Barrack H. Obama", "Donald J. Trump"};
        //Print the array values using the printPresidentNames method
        ArraysLab1.printPresidentNames();
        //Sort the array of names
        Arrays.sort(PresidentNames);
        //Reprint the array values using the printPresidentNames method
        ArraysLab1.printPresidentNames();
    }

    public static void printPresidentNames()
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(PresidentNames));
    }
}
```

Trying to use the method printPresidentNames to output the contents of the array PresidentNames, all I get for output is [null, null, null, null]

Comment: Just remove the `String[]` from the first line of the main function and it will work correctly.

Comment: @jrook did that, compiler throws an error reading "Array constants can only be used in initializers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the first line of your `main()` method to:

```
    PresidentNames =  new String[] {"George Bush", "William J. Clinton", "George W. Bush", "Barrack H. Obama", "Donald J. Trump"};
```

Because `PresidentNames` is a field in your class and you need to initialize it. In the current code, it is defined as a local variable to the `main()` method. Here is a good [explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) on class members.

Comment: This fixes it. So this means I need to initialize it once then initialize it again when I'm adding data to it?

Comment: When I remove the original initialization, it cannot be resolved in any method. I've come to the conclusion that I need to initialize this twice or else it crashes and burns.

Comment: Just try `static String[] PresidentNames;` and see if it works :)